# Powershell Find Replace & Backup

Tags: powershell, replace, find, backup, back

Right now, i am looking to improve my code to use less space and be more intelligent, i need the below code to only backup files IF it's modified by the Find & Replace, right now i'm doing a backup of everything and overwriting old back-ups.

The next thing i would like would be to NOT overwrite the backups, but instead give them a number, so if there are 2 of the same backups in the "backup" folder it would look like this:

> Filebackup.DCN3 -> Filebackup1.DCN3

So i always have the original file.

```
get-childitem -path "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Eurocard\SEB" -filter *.* -recurse | copy-item -destination "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Eurocard\Backup" 

(Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Eurocard\SEB\*.*" -recurse).FullName |
  Foreach-Object {
   (Get-Content $_ -Raw).
     Replace('*','Æ'). 
     Replace('"','Æ').
     Replace('#','Æ').
     Replace('¤','Æ').
     Replace('&','Æ').
     Replace('(','Æ').
     Replace(')','Æ').
     Replace('=','Æ').
     Replace('?','Æ').
     Replace('´','Æ').
     Replace('`','Æ').
     Replace('|','Æ').
     Replace('@','Æ').
     Replace('£','Æ').
     Replace('$','Æ').
     Replace('{','Æ').
     Replace('[','Æ').
     Replace(']','Æ').
     Replace('}','Æ').
     Replace('^','Æ').
     Replace('~','Æ').
     Replace('¨','Æ').
     Replace('*','Æ').
     Replace('<','Æ').
     Replace('>','Æ').
     Replace('\','Æ').
     Replace('_','Æ').
     Replace(';','Æ').
     Replace('.','Æ').
     Replace('!','Æ')|
   Set-Content $_
  }
```

Is there anyone who can help with this ?

Comment: Do you actually have to replace those characters or are you just doing it to make identifying files easier?

Comment: I NEED to replace them, as the system cannot handle these special characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to start a large portion of your regex replaces probably aren't working, you need to escape most of them...for example "\". Anyways you can shorten up the whole replace to one expression like this:

```
-replace '[*"#¤&()=?´`|@£${\[\]}^~¨*<>\\_;.!]','Æ'
#query to show it working
'*"#¤&()=?´`|@£${[]}^~¨*<>\_;.!' -replace '[*"#¤&()=?´`|@£${\[\]}^~¨*<>\\_;.!]','Æ'
```

expanding on that here is how you would get it to only backup if you modify the file:

```
(Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Eurocard\SEB\*.*" -recurse).FullName |
Foreach-Object {
    $Content = (Get-Content $_ -Raw) 
    $Regex = '[*"#¤&()=?´`|@£${\[\]}^~¨*<>\\_;.!]'
    If ($Content | Select-String $Regex -Quiet)
    {
        $Content -Replace $Regex,'Æ'        
        <#
        rest of code block such as copies, backups, renames whatever would go here.
        This way it is only taking place if the file has an unwanted character and is
        modified
        #>        
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks alot :)
Now i just need to make a backup of the original file, and get it to replace the changes.

Comment: What is the "-Quiet" for in the If statement ?

Comment: You're quiet welcome. The -Quiet makes it return a true/false value rather than content. So it's just saying if a match is found $true otherwise $false.